# AS400: How do you display which users have what rights on a particular library?

Tags: ibm-midrange

How do you display which users have what rights on a particular library? I want to display all user rights for a particular library.

Answer (score 1):

From a 5250 session, use the Display Object Authority (DSPOBJAUT) command

`DSPOBJAUT OBJ(MYLIB) OBJTYPE(*LIB)`

From the iNav or web based GUI, Databases-->schemas--> right click on the MYLIB object and select permissions.